# Sample Xcode IOS project for Poppler

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf, poppler

I want to test Poppler in my IOS project for Pdf view and rendering. Is there any sample Xcode  project that uses Poppler or any step by step guidelines for this? I want to use it for iPad.

Comment: why not download and compile the source yourself? It's just a C library...

Comment: well - basically help I am looking for is kickstart to read pdf using Poppler in IOS.

Comment: It is not straightforward to build. it has many dependencies which should be built for ios